# Using the parameters given in stored procedure in a trigger function

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

I would like to know if it is possible to use the parameter "delivery_date_ which is given to the stored procedure "delivery" inside trigger function "insert_error".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delivery (delivery_date date)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
END;
$BODY$


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_error() RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

--being able to use the parameter "delivery_date" here--

END;
$BODY$


DROP TRIGGER check_insert ON transactions;
CREATE TRIGGER check_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON transactions
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_error();
```

Comment: I think in order to use delivery_date in the insert_error function you would need to pass it in as a parameter the same way that it is passed in to the delivery function. But calling the inster_errror function from within the delivery function should be possible

Comment: If i give the trigger function that same parameter, will it inherit the same value when i call the stored procedure ? @MatthewHart

Comment: The procedure and the function are not linked. If you want to use the same value you will need to explicitly pass it from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_error() RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS
$BODY$
begin
    ------  you can use any of these code: 
    CALL delivery(now()::date); -- call with current datetime
    
    CALL delivery(new."date");  -- call with from inserted date field

    CALL delivery(current_timestamp::date); -- and etc.

    return new; 

END;
$BODY$
```